# Removing default item selected SELECT2

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I wonder how can I remove the selected item in SELECT2. Because by default it adds an item selected in the first case. But I need you any be selected by default.

For when it loads the page, I try to click on the first item. It does not return the change event because the item is already selected.

```
aria-selected = "true"

$ (".select"). select2 ({
placeholder: "Select an Item"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to attach to the `select2:close` event and capture the selected value that way.

```
$('.select').on('select2:close', function(){
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
});
```

This will allow you to capture the value of the already selected first item without relying on the `change` event.